# Sincronizar objetos, de um mesmo Array, com o index de páginas diferentes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directives

Uso o [angular-bootstrap-lightbox](https://github.com/compact/angular-bootstrap-lightbox), que serve para mostrar imagens ampliadas, ao clicar sobre 
elas.

Coloquei as imagens em páginas diferentes, usando o `ng-repeat` e o filtro personalizado`| filterBy: ['id']: ''"`, só que apenas a imagem do primeiro objeto na lista do Array é ampliada corretamente, os demais eu preciso ir acrescentando +1, +2, +3 e sucessivamente. O terceiro objeto no *Array* só amplia a imagem corretamente se eu acrescentar ($index+2), Ex:

```
$scope.Images = 
[
   { id="1", url: "/images/img-1.jpg", src: "/images/img-1.jpg"
   },
   { id="2", url: "/images/img-2.jpg", src: "/images/img-2.jpg"
   },
   { id="3", url: "/images/img-3.jpg", src: "/images/img-3.jpg"
   } 

];
```

O objeto que é o primeiro na lista do *Array* `$scope.images` funciona normalmente

```
 <div ng-controller="QuadrinhosCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat="image in images | filterBy: ['id']: '1'">
   <a ng-click="openLightboxModal($index)" title="Ampliar Imagem">
    <img ng-src="{{image.src}}" width="655" height="406" class="img-thumbnail" >
    </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

O objeto que é o segundo na lista do *Array* `$scope.images` só funciona se eu acrescentar +1 no `$index`

```
<div ng-controller="QuadrinhosCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat="image in images | filterBy: ['id']: '2'">
   <a ng-click="openLightboxModal($index+1)" title="Ampliar Imagem">
    <img ng-src="{{image.src}}" width="655" height="406" class="img-thumbnail" >
    </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

O objeto que é o terceiro na lista do *Array* `$scope.images` só funciona se eu acrescentar +2 no `$index`

```
<div ng-controller="QuadrinhosCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat="image in images | filterBy: ['id']: '3'">
   <a ng-click="openLightboxModal($index+2)" title="Ampliar Imagem">
    <img ng-src="{{image.src}}" width="655" height="406" class="img-thumbnail" >
    </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

A chamada padrão para a diretiva, que é inserida no *controller*:

```
$scope.openLightboxModal = function (index) {
  Lightbox.openModal($scope.images, index);
  };
```

Tentei algumas formas mais não obtive exito, como solucionar esse problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postei a dúvida no github do criador da diretiva, ele me orientou, e passou a funcionar redondinho.

Mudar o método no `controller`, para passar a procurar o `index` do `array` baseado no `objeto` determinado pela `image`.

```
$scope.openLightboxModal = function (image) {
  Lightbox.openModal($scope.images, $scope.images.indexOf(image));
};
```

Nesse trecho do código precisa mudar o `$index` para `image`

```
<div ng-controller="QuadrinhosCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat="image in images | filterBy: ['id']: '3'">
   <a ng-click="openLightboxModal(image)" title="Ampliar Imagem">
    <img ng-src="{{image.src}}" width="655" height="406" class="img-thumbnail" >
    </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Obrigado aos que contribuiram e aos que tentaram ajudar, valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Bom, pelo que eu entendi, você esta filtrando para aparecer só o item com aquele id especifico, se quiser que apareça todos basta remover o filtro, que no caso ficaria assim:

```
<div ng-repeat="image in images">
```

Se quiser que só apareça a imagem escolhida ai sim você adiciona o filterBy

```
<div ng-repeat="image in images | filterBy: ['id']: 'aqui vai o id'">
```

Você pode também ordenar por id que ficaria assim:

```
<div ng-repeat="image in images | orderBy: ['id']: true">
```

*se colocar false ao invés de true ele ordena do maior id para o menor, que é chamado de reverse

Comment: O filtro personalizado (https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) é necessário para que eu consiga colocar os objetos em páginas diferentes. Isso funciona bem. O problema é apenas no ($index) mesmo,  que, para ampliar a imagem equivalente a da página preciso ir acrescentando no ($index+1), ($index+2), ($index+3) e sucessivamente para cada novo objeto no array.